# Dockerfile RUN command return an exec format error

Tags: python, linux, docker, flask

I am trying to create and image from my Python Flask app, but I am still getting this format error and I have no idea why. (I am running it on a Raspberry with Raspbian)

> Step 4/5 : RUN echo "test"  ---> Running in ca7b48ab3d4e
> standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format
> error"
>
> The command '/bin/sh -c echo "test"' returned a non-zero code: 1

Here is my Dockerfile

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

FROM python:3.6.1-alpine
WORKDIR /project
ADD . /project
RUN echo "test"
CMD ["python3","careerdigest.py"]
```

I think that there is a problem with bash, because it says, that it calls this command with sh, but I do not know, what I am missing.

This echo command will be replaced by `RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt` to install dependencies.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Check this --> https://github.com/nicolargo/glances/issues/1479 if it is of any help. Seems like issues with building docker image on ARM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I manage to finally run it. I just replace Python image with this one - https://hub.docker.com/r/balenalib/raspberry-pi-python and now it works.